# How would I create bootstrap rows out of this? (React JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, dictionary, reactjs

I currently have the following array of objects, there are twelve of them:

```
{  
   data:[  
      {  
         type:"tweets",
         id:"1",
         attributes:{  
            user_name:"AKyleAlex",
            tweet:"<a href="            https://twitter.com/Javi" target="_blank">@Javi</a> this photos in accurate,
            the front went down causing the back to go up. Hahaha",
            time_ago:"13 hours ago",
            created_at:{  
               date:"2015-12-23 06:15:19.000000",
               timezone_type:3,
               timezone:"UTC"
            },
            updated_at:{  
               date:"2015-12-23 06:15:19.000000",
               timezone_type:3,
               timezone:"UTC"
            }
         }
      },
      {  
         type:"tweets",
         id:"2",
         attributes:{  
            user_name:"AKyleAlex",
            tweet:"<a href="            https://twitter.com/jesse_squires" target="_blank">@jesse_squires</a> C?",
            time_ago:"1 day ago",
            created_at:{  
               date:"2015-12-23 06:15:19.000000",
               timezone_type:3,
               timezone:"UTC"
            },
            updated_at:{  
               date:"2015-12-23 06:15:19.000000",
               timezone_type:3,
               timezone:"UTC"
            }
         }
      },
      {  
         type:"tweets",
         id:"3",
         attributes:{  
            user_name:"AKyleAlex",
            tweet:"Working on my new site :) Super exited.",
            time_ago:"1 day ago",
            created_at:{  
               date:"2015-12-23 06:15:19.000000",
               timezone_type:3,
               timezone:"UTC"
            },
            updated_at:{  
               date:"2015-12-23 06:15:19.000000",
               timezone_type:3,
               timezone:"UTC"
            }
         }
      },
      {  
         type:"tweets",
         id:"4",
         attributes:{  
            user_name:"AKyleAlex",
            tweet:"<a href="            https://twitter.com/javi" target="_blank">@javi</a> Oh. Well what a troll.",
            time_ago:"1 day ago",
            created_at:{  
               date:"2015-12-23 06:15:19.000000",
               timezone_type:3,
               timezone:"UTC"
            },
            updated_at:{  
               date:"2015-12-23 06:15:19.000000",
               timezone_type:3,
               timezone:"UTC"
            }
         }
      },
      {  
         type:"tweets",
         id:"5",
         attributes:{  
            user_name:"AKyleAlex",
            tweet:"<a href="            https://twitter.com/javi" target="_blank">@javi</a> was there a reason they need to stay? a specific reason?",
            time_ago:"1 day ago",
            created_at:{  
               date:"2015-12-23 06:15:19.000000",
               timezone_type:3,
               timezone:"UTC"
            },
            updated_at:{  
               date:"2015-12-23 06:15:19.000000",
               timezone_type:3,
               timezone:"UTC"
            }
         }
      },
      {  
         type:"tweets",
         id:"6",
         attributes:{  
            user_name:"AKyleAlex",
            tweet:"<a href="            https://twitter.com/pearsonified" target="_blank">@pearsonified</a> ugh,
            welcome to 27,
            the new 38",
            time_ago:"1 day ago",
            created_at:{  
               date:"2015-12-23 06:15:19.000000",
               timezone_type:3,
               timezone:"UTC"
            },
            updated_at:{  
               date:"2015-12-23 06:15:19.000000",
               timezone_type:3,
               timezone:"UTC"
            }
         }
      },
      {  
         type:"tweets",
         id:"7",
         attributes:{  
            user_name:"AKyleAlex",
            tweet:"<a href="            https:            //twitter.com/bobbybigwheel" target="_blank">@bobbybigwheel</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/_alastair" target="_blank">@_alastair</a> ha!",
            time_ago:"1 day ago",
            created_at:{  
               date:"2015-12-23 06:15:19.000000",
               timezone_type:3,
               timezone:"UTC"
            },
            updated_at:{  
               date:"2015-12-23 06:15:19.000000",
               timezone_type:3,
               timezone:"UTC"
            }
         }
      },
      {  
         type:"tweets",
         id:"8",
         attributes:{  
            user_name:"AKyleAlex",
            tweet:"RT <a href="            https:            //twitter.com/dan_abramov" target="_blank">@dan_abramov</a>:            Redux being ported to Swift:            <a href="https:            //t.co/JLnIXivsG8" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">https://t.co/JLnIXivsG8</a>",
            time_ago:"1 day ago",
            created_at:{  
               date:"2015-12-23 06:15:19.000000",
               timezone_type:3,
               timezone:"UTC"
            },
            updated_at:{  
               date:"2015-12-23 06:15:19.000000",
               timezone_type:3,
               timezone:"UTC"
            }
         }
      },
      {  
         type:"tweets",
         id:"9",
         attributes:{  
            user_name:"AKyleAlex",
            tweet:"<a href="            https:            //twitter.com/queerdiscox" target="_blank">@queerdiscox</a> <a href="https:            //twitter.com/stanboyet" target="_blank">@stanboyet</a> because:racism",
            time_ago:"1 day ago",
            created_at:{  
               date:"2015-12-23 06:15:19.000000",
               timezone_type:3,
               timezone:"UTC"
            },
            updated_at:{  
               date:"2015-12-23 06:15:19.000000",
               timezone_type:3,
               timezone:"UTC"
            }
         }
      },
      {  
         type:"tweets",
         id:"10",
         attributes:{  
            user_name:"AKyleAlex",
            tweet:"<a href="            https:            //twitter.com/ashfurrow" target="_blank">@ashfurrow</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/javi" target="_blank">@javi</a> I loved ate the original article so hard ….",
            time_ago:"1 day ago",
            created_at:{  
               date:"2015-12-23 06:15:19.000000",
               timezone_type:3,
               timezone:"UTC"
            },
            updated_at:{  
               date:"2015-12-23 06:15:19.000000",
               timezone_type:3,
               timezone:"UTC"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Now for these purposes. I have already saved the data to a variable by doing:

```
self.setState({tweets: data.data});
```

Where `data` is the object above.

In React I am doing (ES6):

```
buildTweets() {

var tweets = this.state.tweets.map(function(tweet){

  return (
    <div className="col-lg-4 cl-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" key={tweet.id}>
      <strong>{tweet.attributes.user_name}</strong>
      <p><span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: tweet.attributes.tweet}} /></p>
      <p><em>Posted: {tweet.attributes.time_ago}</em></p>
    </div>
  );
});

return tweets;
}
```

This is returned and used in the render method as such:

```
return  (
  <div className="row">
    {this.buildTweets()}
  </div>
)
```

Now this, for the most part works. I get all twelve tweets back in columns. Accept it should be 3 columns of `col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12` not 12, like it currently is.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UPDATED: as pointed out, I totally forgot the rows!]

I'm assuming what you're really asking here is to have a bunch of rows, with each row having up to three columns based on the sizes you have already specified. As such:

The `map()` function also gets the current index as it's second parameter. However, since what you really want is an array of a different size than the original, we are going to use `forEach` instead of `map`. Using that + some math, we can accomplish what you want (I've made it full ES6 by the way :D):

```
buildTweets () {
  let rows = [];
  let currCols;
  this.state.tweets.forEach((tweet, i) => {
    if(i % 3 === 0) { // Start of a new row
      if(i > 0) {
        currRows.push(
          <div className='row'>
            {currCols}
          </div>
        );
      }

      currCols = [];
      rows[currRow] = [];
    }

    currCols.push(
      <div className='col-lg-4 cl-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12' key={tweet.id}>
        <strong>{tweet.attributes.user_name}</strong>
        <p><span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: tweet.attributes.tweet}} /></p>
        <p><em>Posted: {tweet.attributes.time_ago}</em></p>
      </div>
    );
  });

  // Handle the last row
  if(currCols.length > 0) {
    currRows.push(
      <div className='row'>
        {currCols}
      </div>
    );
  }

  return rows;
},
render () {
  return  (
    <div id='tweetRowContainer'>
      {this.buildTweets()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This should give you `Math.ceil(tweets / 3)` rows. Each row is promised to have 3 tweets, except for the last row which will have 1-3 tweets.

Comment: I personally hate the arrow function ;P but will for sure try this out and let you know :)

Comment: Feel free to switch them out for 'normal' functions. I've started to really like them because you don't need to worry about having to call `bind(this)` when using arrow functions since `this` is lexically inherited.

Comment: ahem -> `var self = this;` :)

Comment: @KyleAdams tomato, tomahto :)

Comment: So this didn't work: http://i.imgur.com/prTSpat.png You can see how they don't line up. Your render method also doesn't use `row` class. Which I found odd. Even with a row class it still doesn't work. Do you have a fiddle of this?

Comment: @KyleAdams you are totally right! I completely forgot about the rows. I have updated my answer to include them.